# Looking for json data that contains dota2 hero and item details

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

I am working on an application that get response from steam API. I am halfway through my task. Now I need some help on getting response of dota2 hero or item details that completely contains `ìd` `name` and `image_url`.

I want to know are there any steam API call to receive the response that I required?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following steam API call to get `name`, `id` and `localized_name` replace `{ur_key}` with the web API key that steam provided you.

[https://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?key={ur_key}&language=en_us&format=JSON](https://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?key=%7Bur_key%7D&language=en_us&format=JSON)

But you need image URL too, you can use [this](https://github.com/joshuaduffy/dota2api/blob/master/dota2api/ref/heroes.json) json data of `heroes` and [this](https://github.com/joshuaduffy/dota2api/blob/master/dota2api/ref/items.json)  data of `items`

I hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: [This forum](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=58317) would be helpful for you.